# Cross-browser bookmark/add to favorites JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, bookmarks

Is there any cross-browser bookmark/add to favorites using JavaScript.

Searched for some list but none is working. Can you please suggest any?

Comment: I'm thinking no. Bookmarks/favorites should be under the control of the user, imagine if any site you visited could insert itself into your bookmarks with just some javascript.

Comment: I am not asking for automatic bookmarking. A button when clicked should bookmark the current page. I saw many scripts but none were cross browser support

Comment: OK, so you're asking for something that prompts the user whether they want to add your site to bookmarks.  That's a bit different...

Comment: To be honest: if a user needs a button to bookmark the site chances are he/she does not know how bookmarks work. Users who normally use bookmarks know that you can press CTRL+D, drag the little site icon on the bookmark bar, use the menu etc etc.. I find that putting a "bookmark us!" button seems a bit *retro*, so to say. Just make a good website with contents that pushes the user to bookmark it and you won't need any button. (Just my 2¢ on this type of situations, then it's you who have to decide what buttons to put on your website!)

Comment: I am not putting a button in my website ! I am creating a  wordpress plugin. Users who install it get a button to bookmark the current page like the "sociable" plugin

Comment: Cmon, the OP is clearly NOT asking about automatic bookmarking.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**jQuery Version**

JavaScript (modified from a script I found on someone's site - I just can't find the site again, so I can't give the person credit):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bookmarkme").click(function() {
    if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
      window.sidebar.addPanel(location.href,document.title,"");
    } else if(window.external) { // IE Favorite
      window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title); }
    else if(window.opera && window.print) { // Opera Hotlist
      this.title=document.title;
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a id="bookmarkme" href="#" rel="sidebar" title="bookmark this page">Bookmark This Page</a>
```

IE will show an error if you don't run it off a server (it doesn't allow JavaScript bookmarks via JavaScript when viewing it as a `file://...`).

Comment: I wouldn't consider this 'working' - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992844/add-to-browser-favourites-bookmarks-from-javascript-but-for-all-browsers-mine-do/993206#993206 for details

Comment: actually, the FF situation has somewhat improved since my answer because of UI changes, ie the user can now remove the option to open the link in the sidebar when adding the bookmark

Comment: sorry not working for me . I get "Error on page" in IE

Comment: Doesn't this require an external js library as well?

Comment: it requires jQuery Library for the $-Functions.
I would ``.bookmarkme`` use instead of ``#bookmarkme``

Comment: Mozilla sidebar has been removed.  So the top 2 browsers won't work

Comment: Error in Chrome,Uncaught TypeError: window.external.AddFavorite is not a function

Comment: *"If you need a more complete script, you can always buy one from this page"* -- I almost spit my coffee on the screen reading this in 2016. Holy god.

Comment: This answer seems to be obsolete, any update would be welcome.

Answer (score 13):

```js
function bookmark(title, url) {
  if (window.sidebar) { 
    // Firefox
    window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, '');
  } 
  else if (window.opera && window.print) 
  { 
    // Opera
    var elem = document.createElement('a');
    elem.setAttribute('href', url);
    elem.setAttribute('title', title);
    elem.setAttribute('rel', 'sidebar');
    elem.click(); //this.title=document.title;
  } 
  else if (document.all) 
  { 
    // ie
    window.external.AddFavorite(url, title);
  }
}
```

I used this & works great in IE, FF, Netscape.
Chrome, Opera and safari do not support it!

Answer (score 3):

How about using a drop-in solution like [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/) or [AddThis](http://addthis.com/)? They have similar functionality, so it's quite possible they already solved the problem.

AddThis's code has a huge if/else browser version fork for saving favorites, though, with most branches ending in prompting the user to manually add the favorite themselves, so I am thinking that no such pure JavaScript implementation exists.

Otherwise, if you only need to support IE and Firefox, you have IE's [window.externalAddFavorite( )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535926(VS.85).aspx) and Mozilla's [window.sidebar.addPanel( ).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.sidebar)

Comment: addthis is now dead.