# Javascript help needed with bookmark

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarks

Hey I have this little javascript bookmark

`javascript:(function(){ window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?currentsite#bookmark'); })()`

How can I get the url of the current website into that url? 
I have heard of using `document.URL` But I am not sure how to get that into the URL in the bookmark with the URL of the site currently browsing. Meaning at the moment the result is `http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?currentsite=document.URL#bookmark`

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript

Comment: That does not really answer my question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
javascript:(function(){ window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?currentsite=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '#bookmark'); })()
```

Comment: Imagine the current location has query parameters as well? :)

Answer (score 2):

try
window.location or document.location.href or window.location.href
I forgot which one works :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead:

```
javascript:( function(){window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?'+document.location.href+'#bookmark');} )()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use window.location.href - like this:

```
window.open( 'http://<someurl>?' + window.location.href + '#somebookmark' );
```

window.location.href will give you the href of current frame.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are talking about but if you are trying to get the full URL along with the anker you can `document.location.href` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_url.asp

You can access the parts of the URL using Location Object http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

your code should look like this:

```
function(){ 
    var url = document.location.href;
    window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?currentsite = ' + url); 
}
```

Not sure if thats what you where trying to do.