# Javascript bookmark button

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it is possible to create a 'Bookmark this' button using javascript that will add the page URL and page title to the user's bookmarks.

Does anyone know a way of doing this or if it is even possible?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser bookmark/add to favorites javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript)

Comment: Most solutions have not worked since 1999. Browsers have a bookmark feature built in, people should be able to use it if they want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep - without giving you the *best* way of doing it - here's a horrible DHTML solution:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/addbook.htm

Comment: thanks very much for this! I found an answer similar to this while searching myself but it didn't seem to work

Comment: Cross browser bookmark management can be an issue - I would avoid it if possible ;)