# Is there a way to detect in browser if user clicked on "Save as" or bookmarked the page?

Tags: javascript, browser, applet, webbrowser-control, javascript-framework

I am writing a browser data analyzer which detects user activities and sends to server. This way server can provide some personalization based on users interest.

I am trying to intercept when user bookmarks page or saves the page. Then I would send this information to server so as server knows more details about users interest.

I know usually we track users interest based on what links he clicked. But I want to add more functionality to this by including client side tracking also.

I am not sure if we can do using javascript. If not javascript, can I do using something else..like an applet probably?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For Bookmark use this : http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=630903

Comment: I would say that it should be impossible for the webpage to tell if it had been bookmarked or if it had been saved.

Comment: @Arpit That's for an *extension*, not normal JS.

Comment: I think it is more common to just use mouse/click tracking. That can gather *alot* of use information without needing to see what was bookmarked. Also, bookmarking is usually less exciting than actually re-visiting .. saving is a different issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to intercept whether a user bookmarks a page.  [You could add a button that adds the page to their favorites and track that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript)  It won't track whether or not they add it through other means though.