# All browsers "bookmark" link in JavaScript working with FF23+

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

Since Firefox deprecated `window.sidebar.addPanel` in version 23, is  there a javascript code to bookmark a page with an image or link? I'm looking for an "all browser" version of the code, like the one that used to work here: [How do I add an "Add to Favorites" button or link on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033215/add-to-favorites-button/)
Thank you!

Comment: how about : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript

Comment: how about forgetting bookmark button and focus on making good content, so user will manually bookmark your page?

Comment: @RémiBenoit as I said, `window.sidebar.addPanel` has been deprecated in FF23. There has to be a new way, no?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691647

Comment: It seems you won't have an "*all browsers*" solution:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/23/Site_compatibility#DOM