# Is it possible to make an "add to favorites" feature using cookies?

Tags: php, mysql, html, cookies

I want to make a function using php, where guests can add posts to their favorites (so no signup is needed). I tried using MySQL but I got to a dead end because I couldn't find a way to determine a unique device.
Some people  have told me that I can do the same thing using cookies, can anyone tell me how?

Comment: i wouldn't bother with out a login system, what happens when the user deletes cookie

Comment: if javascript is an option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript

Comment: You could set a cookie upon first visit with a unique id? You could then use MySQL and link the unique id in the cookie to a favourited item. You can't do anything about people that clear their cookies, though.

Comment: I'd also look into using the browser local storage mechanism, downside is the only way to consume this data is via Javascript (meaning you don't get a nice cookie sent with the request), but it does increase your storage capacity, and less "noise" with every page request sent to the server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. User clicks "favorite this post" button/link
2. Using PHP you [set the cookie](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) containing favorited post id, along with the already favorites id's that might have been there.
3. On the "your favorite posts" page you retrieve the cookie and query the database for the id's.