# Adding Bookmarks through javaScript for IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have been searching around to figure out if there is any possible way to add bookmarks through javaScript in Internet Explorer 11. One of my friends said he did it but doesn't remember how.

```
window.external.AddFavorite
```

That does not seem to work for Internet Explorer 11. Any help on how it is done, if it is possible, will be really great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript

Comment: I said IE11. I have been through that question, it says IE7.