# Make browser bookmark my link?

Tags: java, javascript, vaadin, bookmarks

I have a vaadin button.
When I click that button I want my browser (firefox) to bookmark a link, lets say www.google.com.

I didn't find much help online.
I found an navigator addon but it doesn't show how to bookmark. https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/navigator

I did spot some Javascript solutions:
[How do I add an "Add to Favorites" button or link on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033215/how-do-i-add-an-add-to-favorites-button-or-link-on-my-website) , [Cross-browser bookmark/add to favorites javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript%20)?

Is java script an option here?

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Vaadin you can execute any javascript code you wish.
In the b[ook of vaadin there is a example](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.javascript.html) on how to acomplish it.

In short you can execute any JS code with this method:

```
// Shorthand
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("alert('Hello')");
```

Of course you will need to find the correct JS code to bookmark your page.
If you wish to bookmark a specific application state/view, then you can use the Navigator for this. (It basically adds a #SomeState to your URL which you can the later come back)