# Bookmark in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to Bookmark using HTML/CSS? I have been developing this mobile application in HTML and want to be able to give the option to bookmark certain pages to the users. Is there a way to do this in HTML?

Comment: You might want to clarify what type of bookmark and the platform you are working with.

Comment: You can to create link and reuest the user drag the link to the bookmark toolbar. For Example, [Drag this link to bookmark toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355278/bookmark-in-html-css)

Comment: i'm building an ebook in HTML/CSS and wanted to give this feature to the user. So they wont be accessing any website. its basically an archived website

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way in pure HTML (since it's just a markup language) or CSS (this just define the style), since bookmarking is an action done exclusively by the browser without iteration with the web page. I'm aware that JavaScript can do it.

Comment: how can i do it in javscript?

Comment: @DarpanPatel Start by doing some research, like Googling "create bookmark with javascript"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, as HTML is only a markup language, not supposed to interfere in browser's data or configuration. In case JavaScript is also an option for you, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024846/3334049).