# Auto Bookmark a Page on Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I wonder if there is a way to **automatically bookmark a page on load** without asking user.

Generally, if you want to bookmark a page or website, you have to press **ctrl+d** or needs to manually click on *Bookmark Star* in browsers like Mozilla and Chrome. Can we do this automatically while loading a page?

I know that this scheme doesn't look honest, but someone challenged that he tried all and there is no way to do this automatically and he boast himself as a JavaScript master.

Comment: You cannot automatically add bookmarks. If you could, a lot of people would overwrite bank of america bookmarks with their phishing ones. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript

Comment: No. Consider how annoying & abused that would be.

Comment: No, you can add a bookmark button, but the browser will still ask you to confirm it.

Comment: @PhilipThomson Dear, so sad. May you please write me that code to add that button, please?