# Trigger ctrl+d programatically in reactjs on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used following node module, no luck

```
import Bookmark from 'react-bookmark';

<Bookmark className="coolClass" href="/cool/path" title="My Cool Website" />
```

And I added following code also, in react functional component.

```
function btnClick(){
    document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'd', 'ctrlKey': true}));   
}
```

My requirement is, on button click it should bookmark in the browser bookmarks list. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript
```

refer to this link this might help you.

Comment: Hi @shilpe, I tried that approach. But it's not worked in my case. Thank you