# Create a Bookmark link that works in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have tried using JavaScript "AddFavorite" function in my code, but it does not work in Safari. It works in IE, I think I remember Firefox, but nothing I have tried seems to work in Safari. All I want to do is have a link on my website that people can click on and it automatically creates a bookmark in their bookmarks folder/bookmark bar.

Does this entail Applescript or something like it? Or a deeper programming language I am unaware of?

```
<a href="javascript:bookmarksite('Name', 'website.com')">
```

Comment: I have tried what I have stated above. JavaScript.

Comment: **facepalm**. Can you please provide the CODE that you've tried?

Comment: @BethanyMichelleStephens what is the code of `bookmarksite` function? Please edit your question with this (don't post it in a comment as the formatting will be removed) Not that it really matters, some browsers just don't allow it. see my answer below.

Comment: @BethanyMichelleStephens no, the actual code of the function. This is just the call to it. Find somewhere in your code where it has something like `function bookmarksite(title, url) { code here }`

Comment: Have you readout this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033215/add-to-favorites-button/10033250#10033250

Answer (score 3):

From the apple forums: [forum-link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1364657?start=0&tstart=0)

> On the Mac side at least, Safari does not allow a website to add a
>   bookmark. I'm pretty sure the same behaviour is in the Windows version
>   as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've been down this road, and what I discovered was that Safari does NOT allow bookmarks to be made with JavaScript:

[Apple Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1364657?tstart=0)

[bytes forum](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/940440-how-add-bookmark-safari-using-javascript)

They consider it unsafe. As frustrating as this is, I get their point.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, most things like this tend to be browser-specific, and picky.

my JS is about level 0, but i did find this on an old article here:

One specifically for Chrome:
[Add to favourites link for Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230499/add-to-favourites-link-for-google-chrome)

And another on a cross-browser bookmark link:
[Cross-browser bookmark/add to favorites javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript)

Hope between the previous comment and these links, you get what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Safari does not allow it for clear security reason.

You could usee a script like this:

http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/javascript/add-bookmark-script/

which handles many browser and has a nice fallback: show a browser customized alert with instructuion message.

Es: in chrome it says: "Ctrl+D to add as bookmark"

Answer (score -1):

In IE something similar to the following would work: ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535926%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
window.external.AddFavorite(location.href, document.title);
```

However, this won't work in other browsers. In Firefox, I believe you can use

```
window.sidebar.addPanel(document.title, location.href, '');
```

to create a sidebar panel (not a real bookmark) but as far as I know Chrome and Safari do not allow Javascript to automatically create bookmarks. For those, I recommend giving the user the instructions to do it manually:

- drag a link to their bookmarks
- pressing `Ctrl + D` to add a bookmark
- Clicking `+` or star icon in the toolbar