# How can I use JS to add a bookmark specifically in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

After reading [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992844/add-to-browser-favorites-bookmarks-from-javascript-but-for-all-browsers-mine-doe), I started using [this javascript "plugin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992844/add-to-browser-favorites-bookmarks-from-javascript-but-for-all-browsers-mine-doe/4583290#4583290) across my websites.  However recently a client told me that it isn't working in IE9.  I use Windows XP so I can't test IE9 but I'm 99% sure he's telling the truth.  Any ideas?

Comment: Don't understand why this is getting downvotes...

Comment: This post has attracted 2 spam/offensive flags, which explain 2/3 of the downvotes. I don't know why someone would flag it as your link seems reasonable.

Comment: @Marcog: link to js file is a porn site - had I been at work, the link would have triggered the ADULT SITE WARNING on my browser - I have edited the question to point at the post here at SO that shows the actual code

Comment: @mplungjan Ok, that explains it. Thanks for changing the link. Hopefully people don't overlook the change and the post remains.

Comment: If you re-read my answer you will see I was not trying to kid or annoy you.

Answer (score 0):

The code you suggested (copyrighted by a porn site) tests MSIE 8 and higher and uses  [window.external.AddToFavoritesBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which was introduced in IE8.
I have now successfully tested your suggested code it on [**>>THIS PAGE<<**](http://plungjan.name/test/testaddtofavorites.html) in the following browsers - all on windows XP except IE9 which I tested on vanilla default win7 installation (IE9 only runs on Win7 or an upgraded Vista)

- IE9 - bookmarks
- IE8 - bookmarks
- Safari5 - shows ctrl-d
- Chrome10 - shows ctrl-d
- Fx4 - bookmarks in sidebar
- Opera v11 - bookmarks
- Mozilla 1.7 - does not show the link.

So the answer to your question is: The code you want to use should work and does work in a standard installation of windows 7 with IE9 default install.

---

For the readers of this question, here is something much simpler which will work on all browsers (except, for some weird reason, Chrome), simply do this:

```
Page bookmark (Please right-click to bookmark): <a title="Title of the bookmark (for Opera)"
href="http://fullyQualifiedUrlToYourSite.com/page.html">Title of the bookmark</a>
```

or if you insist:

```
Page bookmark (Please right-click to bookmark): 
<a title="Title of the bookmark (for Opera)"
href="http://fullyQualifiedUrlToYourSite.com/page.html"
oncontextmenu="if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')!=-1) 
alert('Click ctrl-d to bookmark, as you already know as a Chrome-using techie')" 
>Title of the bookmark</a>
```

Comment: Sorry about the porn, I just linked to the js file so I assumed it wouldn't be an issue -- curiousity killed the cat ;).  Your example looks like it is just a link?  I feel like maybe you just forgot something...

Comment: Nope I did not forget anything. Since the js you gave only actually works in IE (addtosidebar is not bookmarking) then I decided to show you how to not have to use such incredibly unwieldy script for something that simple. Right clicking is one action more than you have now, and it works for all browsers on mac, linux and windows PCs and on several smartphones too, Period. And the js had the name and title of the site inside.

Comment: actually, you are forgetting title attribute

Comment: @Free Who is forgetting which title attribute?

Comment: @mplungjan -- I see, totally not what I want man.  Also you can't right click a link and add to bookmark in Chrome.  Either of those a good reason to downvote...

Comment: You cannot do any of the stuff you want in Google Chrome anyway, so that is not a valid reason for down voting my answer.

Comment: @mplungjan, you are. Opera 10+ wants .title instead of .textContent

Comment: @Andrew: Just to show you I do not bear grudges, I fixed your question to stop it from being flagged as offensive

Comment: @mplungjan -- no offense intended, the script I provided does a `alert("Press CTRL+D To Bookmark")` when in Chrome which is exactly what I want as a fallback.

Comment: The difference is, that **HAD** chrome behaved like all other browsers, the text in the title/innertext is what will be the title of the bookmark - ctrl-d will take whatever the title is of the page you are on, perhaps not what you want to bookmark.

Comment: I don't want to sit here and bicker but your response is basically: forget about Chrome [and Safari and Netscape and iCab and IE5 on Mac] -- dig deep, you know that's totally unacceptable

Comment: @Andrew: See update. You will be happy to notice it works in default installation of IE9 on plain vanilla Win7.

Comment: @Andrew I tested it for you in IE9 and confirmed it works. So the answer is: It works. If not, then there is a restriction on your friend's browser we do not know about

Comment: @mplungjan -- are you kidding me already?  Read the title of the question.  Does your awful answer use JS to add a bookmark in IE9?  No it doesn't.  I want a click here to bookmark link.  Your response is just write the text "please bookmark" -- absolutely stupid.  Period.

Comment: @Andrew Please click the link I posted in my text: [tested on **THIS PAGE**](http://plungjan.name/test/testaddtofavorites.html) which tests YOUR code in IE9